# Capybara - Not catching Angular2 URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a test written in rspec that checks for a path after clicking a link:

```
click_link("Dew, Muntain A")
expect(current_path).to eq(demographic_information_patient_path(1))
```

Now, here I get:

```
current_path = "/"
demographic_information_patient_path(1) = "/patients/1/demographics"
```

Hence, the test fails. What I can see is, after the link is clicked, the next page is indeed demographics page with URL "/patients/1/demographics", but somehow capybara isn't able to find it.

**NOTE:** When I manually try the test and print `request.url` in rails controller, I get `"/patients/1/demographics"`

One reason I can thing off is, the page being hit is an Angular2 page, is it because of that capybara is unable to find the correct URL?

My Tries with capybara:

```
URI.parse(current_url).request_uri #gives "/"
page.current_url #gives "/"
u = page.execute_script("window.location.url"); #gives nil as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

Capybara's `click_xxx` methods just click the item mentioned. They don't wait for the action caused by the click to occur because they have no idea what that action is going to be.  Because of that you shouldn't be using the `eq` matcher with `current_path`, rather you should be using the `have_current_path` matcher which has waiting/retrying behavior built-in

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(demographic_information_patient_path(1))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have changed the code as you suggested, but I'm getting this error:

**Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_current_path(demographic_information_patient_path(1))
expected #<Capybara::Session:0x0000000c47f548> to respond to `has_current_path?`**

Comment: @Abhi  What version of Capybara are you using?  The `have_current_path` matcher was added in version 2.5.0 nearly 18 months ago, you may need to update.  Alternatively, maybe you haven't required `capybara/rspec` in your spec_helper - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec ?